# Timezone Datetime with offset in php , getting it easy

Tags: php, date, timezone

I have timestamp from specific timezone (Jamaica) and i want to get GMT timestamp of it. Is there more elegant solution than this one :

```
$start = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', 1330560000);
        $start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Jamaica'));
        $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');//2012-02-29 19:00:00 NO NO NO

        $tz = new DateTimeZone( 'America/Jamaica' );
        $transition = $tz->getTransitions($start->getTimestamp(),$start->getTimestamp());


        $offset = $transition[0]['offset'];


        $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $params['start'] - 2*$transition[0]['offset']);
        $start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Jamaica'));
        $start->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // "2012-03-01 05:00:00" YESSSS!!!
```

Comment: Timestamps are invariant across timezones. Specifically, `1330560000` is 2012-03-01 00:00:00 UTC. If that's not the time you want, the code that produced this timestamp is buggy.

Comment: @Jon 1330560000 is Jamaican( or any other time zone with | without  DST ) time and I need UTC time ( 2012-03-01 05:00:00)

Comment: @user1222955: No, 1330560000 is not "Jamaican time". It is *a specific moment in time*, which is 00:00:00 in UTC and 2012-02-29 19:00:00 in Jamaica (obvious, UTC-5). What PHP does here is correct; it's your expectations that are wrong. If the result that should be reached is the one you expect, the code that produced the timestamp is also wrong.

Comment: Can you help me write function that somehow assume that is actually  2012-03-01 00:00:00 Jamaican time and that it need be converted to UTC, 2012-03-01 05:00:00?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a part of my class that create a well-formatted time stamp as I wrote in the comment of the function, it's very easy to use just pass the string of the date, time zone and the identifier.

Hope it helps you

```
/**
* Default timestamp format for formatted_time
* @var  string
*/
public static $timestamp_format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
/**
* Returns a date/time string with the specified timestamp format
* @example $time = Date::formatted_time('5 minutes ago');
* @link    http://www.php.net/manual/datetime.construct
* @param   string  $datetime_str       datetime string
* @param   string  $timestamp_format   timestamp format
* @param   string  $timezone           timezone identifier
* @return  string
*/
public static function formatted_time($datetime_str = 'now', $timestamp_format = NULL, $timezone = NULL){
            $timestamp_format = ($timestamp_format == NULL) ? Date::$timestamp_format : $timestamp_format;
            $timezone         = ($timezone === NULL) ? Date::$timezone : $timezone;
            $tz   = new DateTimeZone($timezone ? $timezone : date_default_timezone_get());
            $time = new DateTime($datetime_str, $tz);
            if ($time->getTimeZone()->getName() !== $tz->getName()){
                $time->setTimeZone($tz);
            }
            return $time->format($timestamp_format);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Unix time, or POSIX time, is a system for describing instances in time, defined as the number of seconds that have elapsed since midnight **Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)**, 1 January 1970.

source [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

The idea of the UNIX timestamp is that it is always in UTC (everywhere in the world xD ). If it does not represents the time in UTC it's not a UNIX timestamp anymore

Comment: thanks for clarification. Ok, so 1330560000 is jamaican time , not UTC. I want UTC

Comment: @user1222955 It IS UTC, not jamaican. Just set GMT time zone and then format your DateTime. In script you posted change line 2 to `$start->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT'));`, and delete that ... whatever that is after line 4. DateTime::format() formats time for current timezone that is set for it. So if you want it to print GMT time - feed it with GMT DateTimeZone. Want it jamaican again - set timezone back to jamaica. And timestamp is always UTC, it's equal in whole world unless your clock is set wrong.